# Google API console 1 api request counts 10quota

Tags: api, google-places-api, google-api-console

Is there any bug on Google API Console? 
When I make exact 1 request via postman to Google API console, it counts 10 quota per request.

What did I wrong?

Any suggestions welcome, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on [limits and billing](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage) page

Note: The Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier. That is, each Text Search request that you make will count as 10 requests against your quota.